# aliased templates in nested classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias

I am trying to get a template alias for `T2<B>` starting from an instance of C.

```
template<typename A>
struct T1
{
   template<typename B>
   struct T2{};
};

template<typename A>
class C
{
   T1<A> t;
};

template<typename A>
using U1=decltype(C<A>::t);

template<typename A, typename B>
using U2=typename U1<A>::T2<B>;
```

I get a compiler failure with gcc 4.8:

```
gg.cc:18:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
 using U2=typename U1<A>::T2<B>;
```

I have used the typename keyword in every sensible location, but can't get the U2 definition to compile.

What is the correct syntax here? It would be even better if I could get a definition of U2 without resorting to U1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `template` disambiguator to tell the compiler to parse `T2` as the name of a template (and the subsequent `<` and `>` as delimiters of the corresponding template arguments):

```
    template<typename A, typename B>
    using U2=typename U1<A>::template T2<B>;
//                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Here is a compiling [live example](http://ideone.com/gm4Z1D).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) you can find some more information on when you should use the `template` disambiguator (and the `typename` disambiguator as well, although you seem to be aware of that one).

Comment: I have only seen this in member template functions before. Thanks, I would never have found this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler compiles the following:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
using U2=typename U1<A>::T2<B>;
```

After it reads the nested name specifier `U1<A>::`, it doesn't know which specialization of `U1` it is in, because `A` is unknown.  Each `U1` specializaiton could be totally different, and depend on what `A` is.  So it has no idea what kind of name `T1` is.  In particular it doesn't know whether it is a template name or not.  (For example `U1<int>::T1` could be totally different to what `U1<char>::T1` is.)

For this reason you need to explicitly tell the compiler that `T1` is going to be a template name by using the `template` keyword before `T1`.